# how to cast/parse Axios REST response field from string to Date within React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, axios, fetch-api

What would be the easiest way to effectively "convert" (parse/cast) the Date strings from a REST API response to true Dates?  So that after "setItems" is called the contents of "items" is correctly typed as per the "ItemsType".  Is there an easy way to do this in TypeScript/javascript?

Code below.  Currently when I call setItems everything remains as strings, even though I have called out the items variable should be of type "ItemsType[]", so I guess it's not as if typing the variable magically makes it happen, and in fact there is no error thrown.

```
type ItemsType = {
  id: number
  locationName: string
  checkinDate: Date
  checkoutDate: Date   // edited-this shoudl have been Date also
}

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<ItemsType[]>([])
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`https://localhost:7040/Tripstop`)
        const rawItems = await res.data
        setItems(typedItems)
      }
    )()
  }, [])
```

Sample incoming REST data:

[image]

Comment: Map them via the `Date` constructor... `rawItems.map(({ checkinDate, checkoutDate, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, checkinDate: new Date(checkinDate), checkoutDate: new Date(checkoutDate) }))`. Keep in mind that they will be interpreted as local (to the client) timezones

Comment: Phil - I was more after some declaritive/standard way react coders would tackle the problem, or using Axios or something...

Comment: Phil - just saw your 2nd comment.  I'll try this out.  Still wondering if there isn't a more declaritive way of doing this for a REST call with react and axios.  Or perhaps this is how everyone does it(?)

Comment: I was interested... So this came to mind : https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-aryabhata-bju2td?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always implement a generic Axios response transformer to decode anything that looks like a date.

For example, this creates an Axios instance that transforms any value with the word *"date"* in the key

```ts
const dateKeyRx = /date/i;

export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:7040/",
  transformResponse: (data) =>
    JSON.parse(data, (key, value) =>
      dateKeyRx.test(key) ? new Date(value) : value
    ),
});
```

But I'd be more inclined to create a service for retrieving and transforming specific responses. This would encapsulate your logic without exposing the specific implementation to any consumers.

For example

```ts
// svc/tripstop.ts

import axios from "axios";

interface ResponseItem {
  id: number;
  locationName: string;
  checkinDate: string;
  checkoutDate: string;
}

export interface ItemsType extends ResponseItem {
  checkinDate: Date;
  checkoutDate: Date;
}

export const getTripstop = async (): Promise<ItemsType[]> => {
  const { data } = await axios.get<ResponseItem[]>(
    "https://localhost:7040/Tripstop"
  );
  return data.map(({ checkinDate, checkoutDate, ...rest }) => ({
    ...rest,
    checkinDate: new Date(checkinDate),
    checkoutDate: new Date(checkoutDate),
  }));
};
```

Then you can use it in your React components

```ts
import { getTripstop } from "./svc/tripstop";

// ... snip

useEffect(() => {
  getTripstop().then(setItems).catch(console.error);
}, []);
```

---

You could still use the response transformer which would save you the extra `.map()` call

```ts
export const getTripstop = async () =>
  (await api.get<ItemsType[]>("/Tripstop")).data;
```

Comment: thanks Phil - this looks great.  Do you know if the typing "Promise<ItemsType[]>" and "axios.get<ResponseItem[]>" actually does anything out of curiosity?

Comment: It prevents you from dealing with `any` or `unknown` types which you should always strive to do with Typescript

Answer (score 0):

You can cast something like this

```
const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Array<ItemsType>>([]);

  const getData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://localhost:7040/Tripstop`)
    const rawItems = await res.data as Array<ItemsType>;
    const parsedData = rawItems.map((x) => ({
        ...x,
        checkInDate: new Date(x.checkInDate).toDateString(), 
        checkOutDate: new Date(x.checkOutDate).toDateString()
    }))
    setItems(parsedData)
  }

  useEffect(() => getData(), [])
}
```

Comment: thanks - would you need the "toDateString()" however?

Comment: It depends upon your requirement. Just `new Date('2022-02-02T00:00:00')` will return standard local datte format something like this `Wed Feb 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` and if you use `toDateString()` then the response will be in this format `'Wed Feb 02 2022'`

Comment: I'm not a typescript expert, but when doing "setItems" (noting it's used state has been typed as "ItemsType[]") then I'm assuming they should be Date objects, to match up with the ItemsType.   So then saved as a Date in "items", but could then format them to whatever when in JSX then?    Is this typically what you do for REST API's to convert the data?  (i.e. no special axios "trick" or magic available then)

Comment: PS - thanks again too for the help

Comment: This won't compile because OP's `ItemsType` expects `Date` instance but you are supplying strings

Comment: I changed to this and it seems ok, however just saw you're answer so will look at that next too:          const parsedData = rawItems.map((x:any) => ({
          ...x,
          checkinDate: new Date(x.checkinDate),
          checkoutDate: new Date(x.checkoutDate)
        }))
        setItems(parsedData)